# Display prefix units in excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a specific cell in my excel sheet that contains a value from 0-100 (The value can be changed by the user). Whose value is used in some formulas at different places in the sheet.

I would like to know if there is a trick to display the cell as a string like x60 or x10 etc etc. However, when used in a formula it should be considered as a number like 60 or 10

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please take a minute to clarify your question by using the [edit] link to add details. Do you mean the user enters the number, lets say `60`, but you want Excel to show `x60`? Where should it display this? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you asking for the value in the cell to be different to what is being shown?

Comment: @CharlieRB It should be displayed likewise in the same cell.

Answer (score 2):

Apply a *Custom* format of:

**"X"00**

For example:

[image]